# How to display data using jqgrid in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

Here at below code, the action method which is specified in the URL is not being called at all. can any one help me..?

```html
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>       
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getData() {
        $('#list').jqGrid({
            url: '/Home/gridData/',  // here it is not calling
            datatype: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
            // ...
        });
    }
```

Below one is action method:

```
public JsonResult gridData()
{
    practiceEntities pt = new practiceEntities();    
    var jsonData = pt.tbl_dept.ToList();
    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Check your console for errors. You're including jqGrid *before* jQuery which I can't imagine is going to work too well.

Answer (score 0):

Make a call like this. Remove the back slash (/) from the front and back of URL and there is no need of charset-utf-8

```
  $('#list').jqGrid({
                url: 'Home/gridData',  // here it is not calling
                datatype: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json",
              ...........
              ..........
             });
```

Comment: When you put a backslash in front of your URL,the absolute path comes up differently and without back slash its different. You can try.

Comment: Ya I know, even after putting the Jquery script before jqgrid it is not gonna work Jai.

Comment: after removing the slashes also it is not calling that action method but when i tried to call outside the grid like $.ajax({ url: '/Home/gridData',...}) it is calling why it is happening i don't know..